# what the best documented python friendly GUI builder like GLADE

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pygtk, glade

I stepped into python gui programming and I wanted to know what the best documented GUI builder like GLADE, which I'm using right now, however I struggle so much to find some good tutorials or documentation, mostly in the even handling area.
I would like also to understand what's the best/documented GUI framework.
Thanks to anyone who will answer.

Comment: Glade produces GUI for GTK toolkit, so you'll need to use the GTK documentation http://www.gtk.org/documentation.php, possibly at the C/C++ API docs as well.

Comment: You should consider freeing yourself from being dependant on a gui designer. Sketch out a design on paper then learn how to code the gui by hand. It's really not as hard as it sounds.

Comment: @BryanOakley Free yourself? GUI designers are a tool like any other. They are worth using and speed up the development process. It's not like web dev where there is a wealth of semantic content that editors can't handle correctly.

Comment: @Lattyware: I would argue that there is a wealth of content in a GUI application that GUI designers can't handle, too. Yes, they are a tool like any other, but you are just starting out learning how to create GUIs, I think you will learn a lot through doing them by hand.

Comment: @BryanOakley Then use the tools for what you can do, and your hand elsewhere. Glade is pretty complete though, it helps that the GTK is a relatively small standard compared to something like the web, with one implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Glade. You can use Glade GUIs with Python, and the documentation is there. Glade is simply an editor for the GTK, so you can look through the [pyGTK docs](http://www.pygtk.org/reference.html) for information.

In fact, I even have a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5KrgCrPp3w4) on doing it. It's a bit old now, but should still give the idea.

As for alternatives, the other big one is [QT with QT Designer](https://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/).

Comment: Hehe, I've already watched your videos, nice job at the moment your tutorials have been one of the few good resources I've found so far.Btw thanks a lot for making them.

Comment: @nassio No worries, I'm still shocked by the number of hits they get. I should really do a newer version, as they are getting a bit old and I did them pretty quickly (unscripted) and it shows (I um and er a lot, and there are a few mistakes), but I'm glad they are useful.

Answer (score 3):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/learning). It is VERY well documented. A lot of info in internet.
And it has a lot more stuff inside, not just GUI.

It has Python bindings: [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro)

There are a plenty of tutorials out there. Here are some of them:

- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tutorials.html
- http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/
- http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Tutorials
- http://lionel.textmalaysia.com/a-simple-tutorial-on-gui-programming-using-qt-designer-with-pyqt4.html
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9E2KOphwZMg
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYF0spYkXUs

Comment: Maybe you could comment and add links to Qt graphic based interface design tools, like the ones the O.P. asked?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "best/documented GUI framework". There are many GUI toolkits, all more-or-less equally powerful. Tkinter, PyQT, wxPython... all have their strengths and weaknesses. Pick any one of them and start learning.

I recommend Tkinter for learning, mainly because you probably already have it. Once you understand the fundamentals of event based programming (and Tkinter provides a fairly gentle way to learn that), you'll be in a better position to judge which of the available toolkits fits your definition of "best".

Comment: do you read the question? He wants some IDE for GUI building, not recommendation about BEST word

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo: yes, I did read the question. It was a little vague, since the question starts by asking about a GUI builder, but then the last sentence asks about a framework.  Regardless, the word BEST appears several times in the question.

Answer (score 1):

you'll find some very good and new video tutorials here:
http://vimeo.com/25185245
There made by Daniel G. Siegel, a member of gnome and teach you how to make some small graphic apps.
If i remmember well, he first explains how to create the gui without glade and then introduces it when a more comprehensive ui is needed.